# I am trying $http code for first time but not getting result. What is wrong in my code

Tags: angularjs

I am trying $http service code but not getting the result

this is code for samp.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

   <html>

   <head>

   <title>

AngularJs $http Service Example

     </title>

     <script 
       src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"> 
        </script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
```

```
var app = angular.module('serviceApp', []);

 app.controller('serviceCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {

  $http({

   method: 'GET',

   url: 'welcome.html'

  }).then(function success(response) {

   $scope.myWelcome = response.myWelcome;

    }, function error(response) {

   });

 });
```

```
  <div ng-app="serviceApp" ng-controller="serviceCtrl">

      <p>Hi, Guest</p>

  <h1>{{myWelcome}}</h1>

</div>
```

``````````````````````````````````this is code for welcome.html```````````````

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<body>
<h3>Welcome to my page</h3>
</body>
</html>

I want to get a result like

Hi Guest
Welcome to my Page
```

Comment: Can you log your response once? why are you giving url as welcome.html? and making an http call?

Comment: @vertika how can i write code using http() only

Answer (score 1):

The $http service returns data as the `data` property of the response object:

```
var app = angular.module('serviceApp', []);    
app.controller('serviceCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    $http({method: 'GET',url: 'welcome.html'})
      .then(function success(response) {
         ̶$̶s̶c̶o̶p̶e̶.̶m̶y̶W̶e̶l̶c̶o̶m̶e̶ ̶=̶ ̶r̶e̶s̶p̶o̶n̶s̶e̶.̶m̶y̶W̶e̶l̶c̶o̶m̶e̶;̶
         $scope.myWelcome = response.data.myWelcome;
         console.log(response.data);
    }).catch(function(error) {
         console.log(error);
         throw error;
    });
});
```

For more information, see

- [AngularJS $http Service API Reference - returns](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#$http-returns)